# Move focus to next window does not work on some applications

Tags: macos, focus

I have set a custom shortcut for "Move focus to next window". This works fine on most applications but on some it does not e.g. Android Studio. I could not find a application specific behaviour in the settings that maybe overrides it. Any idea how to find out whats wrong?

Comment: idk Android Studio so I can't test, but try to eliminate possible key conflict by temporarily changing to a much more complex command, ctrl/opt/shift/cmd/[whatever] won't conflict with anything built into any app. Check the app's Window menu is telling the system what windows are present & that they're all in the same Space. The command will not cross Spaces to operate, that includes if you have windows on two displays & 'Displays have separate Spaces' is enabled.

Comment: Chaning to a complex command worked. So it definitely is a application specific behavior. I guess I have to find whats using my preffered command thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio under Settings->Keymap there is a Shortcut for "Next Project Window". After settings this to my preferred shortcut it worked.

I recently updated Android Studio which i guess lead to this problem. In my older versions I have never changed this setting.